# Save and Load ListView content

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, save, restore

I am writing an app in C# winForm, and I am using ListView to store some data.
I need to save this list of item when the form is closed and load it again when the form is opened again.

This is the code to add a new element on the list:

```
string[] timeitem = new string[2];

timeitem[0] = txtDescription.Text;
timeitem[1] = msktime.Text;

ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(timeitem);

lstTimes.Items.Add(lvi);
```

What is the best way to save and load this list? I do not need a Dialog for the user, this list should be saved and loaded automatically each time the user open the form that contains the ListView item. I am open to use either .txt or xml file, whatever is the best/more easy to handle.

Comment: Kinda depends. Is this user data, so you'd store it in like a userconig (possibly xml) file? Do you already have a database that you might would want to save it to..etc..

Comment: Yes this is user data, those are sort of alarm clock settings, I am not using a dasabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple helper class for that:

```
class ListItemsHelper
{
    private const string FILE_NAME = "items.dat";

    public static void SaveData(Items items)
    {
        string data = SerializeItems(items);
        File.WriteAllText(GetFilePath(), data);
    }

    public static Items LoadData()
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(GetFilePath());
        return DeserializeItems(data);
    }

    private static string GetFilePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, FILE_NAME);
    }

    private static string SerializeItems(Items items)
    {
        //Do serialization here
    }

    private static Items DeserializeItems(string data)
    {
        //Do deserialization here
    }
}
```

Use:

```
ItemsStateHelper.SaveData(items);

Items data = ItemsStateHelper.LoadData();
```

Additionally, you would have to include some exception handling and choose where you want to save the file. In the code i posted it is saving on folder where the exe file is located.

Comment: Which using directive should I use for the Items class?

Comment: What do you mean by 'using directive'? I put it as `Items` just for an exemplification, you will have to build your own data structure there.